# Configuring Multi PHP Environment Using Docker

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I would like to configure my machine in such a way that i can easily work on different projects running on different versions of php as well as mysql database. My approach is to use centralized containers.

I have pulled following images.

```
REPOSITORY              TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
bitnami/codeigniter     3                   25da0598c415        2 hours ago         287MB
php                     7.1-apache          3aaef27a36f8        7 days ago          402MB
php                     7.2-apache          071b437a2194        7 days ago          410MB
phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin   latest              91490af22618        10 days ago         454MB
php                     7.3-apache          5af347316d4b        2 weeks ago         410MB
mysql                   5.6                 b3983abaa3fe        2 weeks ago         302MB
mysql                   5.7                 cd3ed0dfff7e        2 weeks ago         437MB
mysql                   8.0                 c8ee894bd2bd        2 weeks ago         456MB
mysql                   latest              c8ee894bd2bd        2 weeks ago         456MB
php                     5.6-apache          24c791995c1e        9 months ago        355MB
php                     7.0-apache          aa67a9c9814f        10 months ago       368MB
```

For the practice i have created different containers using above images

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
e316ebbabad2        mysql:8.0                      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 days ago          Up 11 minutes       33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3308->3306/tcp   mysql80
da8811e5b472        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin          "/docker-entrypoint.…"   7 days ago          Up 11 minutes       0.0.0.0:8003->80/tcp                pma80
3518f98e9fe7        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin          "/docker-entrypoint.…"   7 days ago          Up 10 minutes       0.0.0.0:8002->80/tcp                pma57
e3dbe9ec50b8        mysql:5.7                      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 days ago          Up 10 minutes       33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3307->3306/tcp   mysql57
f0c2e8058b6c        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   7 days ago          Up 10 minutes       0.0.0.0:8001->80/tcp                dbui56
b6cb467b7365        mysql:5.6                      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 days ago          Up 10 minutes       0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp
```

Every container is mapped to different ports:

MySQL5.6
http://localhost:8001/index.php

MySQL5.7
http://localhost:8002/index.php

MySQL8.0
http://localhost:8003/index.php

Let's say i have a project A & B, which i want to run using php7.2 and mysql5.7 but i dont want to create a separate database containers for each of them, instead i would like to use the existing mysql5.7 container which maps to

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE          PORTS                               NAMES
e3dbe9ec50b8        mysql:5.7      33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3307->3306/tcp   mysql57
```

Is it possible to link a single running container to different containers ? If yes then how ?

I would like to know whether my approach is correct or wrong ? If wrong then why ?, If i am working on 5 different projects each having its own database container as well as phpmyadmin wouldn't it be the waste of memory and space. I am not sure what i actually want is possible or not, read many articles but still confused and couldn't pin point from where i should start. Currently i am using different versions of php-fpm with apache on my machine using Ubuntu 18 LTS.